# React Native + Amplify S3 Example

Tags: reactjs, amazon-web-services, react-native, amazon-s3, aws-amplify

I'm looking for a thorough example of how to return the file name after successfully sending it to `S3`.

Currently I have something like:

```
uploadImageAsync = async (pickerResult) => {
    try {
      this.setState({
        uploading: true,
      })

      if (!pickerResult.cancelled) {
        const response = await fetch(pickerResult.uri);
        const blob = await response.blob();
        Storage.put(fileName, blob)
          .then(result => console.log(result))
          .catch(err => console.log(err))
      }
    } finally {
      this.setState({
        uploading: false,
      })
    }
  }
```

My return result is the filename that I created. I'd like to return the S3 filename after it is created. Is this possible?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could perform a `get()` call for the image to get a signed url.

```
Storage.put('profile-picture.jpeg', blob)
  .then(result => {
    Storage.get('profile-picture.jpeg')
      .then(result => {
        console.log(result);                    
      })
      .catch(err => {
        console.error(err);
      });
  })
  .catch(err => {
    console.error(err);
  });
```

Comment: That's what I ended up doing! Thank you so much. I think now displaying it to the user is my next challenge - I saw a few items that seemed helpful but after testing, wasn't ideal... If you have any advice on that I'd love to hear it - since this stuff is so new, the documentation gets very confusing - and doesn't hit the obvious points.

Comment: For displaying images in `react-native`, you can use the built-in `<Image source={{uri: 'some-uri'}} />` or something like [react-native-scalable-image](https://www.npmjs.com/package/react-native-scalable-image). The first solution should work, as your url is signed because you retrieved it with the S3 sdk. Does that answer your question?

Answer (score 3):

So you don't actually need to get the S3 file's key returned back to you after performing a put, because it will always have a predictable key based on the third parameter you supply to "put".

- Public level/omitted third param: "public/yourFileName"
- Protected level/{level: 'protected'}: "protected/IdentityId/fileName"
- Private level/{level: 'private'}: "private/IdentityId/fileName"

The put function automatically composes the prefix to your filename for you. However, you can get the "IdentityId" part like this, if you need it for whatever reason:

```
Auth.currentCredentials().then(user => user.identityId)
```

Comment: Thank you! That's great to know. :)